# Comparing arrays in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays

I am creating a site for a card game and I have a problem with the search function.

I want to allow users to search for cards that match any number of options for a given field (e.g. the cards can be 1 of six different factions and I have a multi select box that allows users to select multiple factions to match).  If the card can only be one of the options then I can simply build the query using the 'IN' sql operator and that works fine.

I run into a problem when the card has multiple subtypes in the database.  Right now I am storing the subtypes as a comma separated list in a single field and I want to use the '&&' operator to compare the 2 sets but that is an array operator and the data in the table apparently isn't stored as an array so it isn't working.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: General hint, never store data as CSVs, and things will become a huge amount easier for you

Comment: The IN operator is used to search for a row which has a column which has a value in a list you provide. It's not the other way around. So if you have a column with 100's of first names you can query: `WHERE \`firstName\` in ('Adam', 'Robert')`. So it's not like searching within a field. It's kind of short for: `WHERE \`firstName\` = 'Adam' OR \`firstName\` = 'Robert'` - although I don't know when either is more efficient or what the tipping point is when the one is more efficient than the other.

Comment: PS: I think you should elaborate on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use comma-separated lists to store your card attributes; that's not going to work.

Either create new columns in your Cards table for each attribute, or join another table that contains the attributes in a one-to-many relationship with your Cards table.

Comment: I'd recommend the second option -- _join another table that contains the attributes in a one-to-many relationship with your Cards table_ -- don't use a separate column for each attribute that will become too difficult to maintain if you have a lot of attributes.

Comment: I can't use a separate column for each possible subtype because there are about 100 possible subtypes and each card is only going to have about 2 or 3 of them so that would be a horrible waste of space.  Is there a way to store data in the dtatabase as an array?

Comment: Create another table that has a one-to-many relationship with your Cards table, and store the attributes (or subtypes, or whatever you're calling them) there, one record per Card-Attribute combination.